# How to subtract time from date

Tags: c++, datetime, time, timespan

Is there standard c++ time class which has methods to subtract dates
for example:
I want to subtract 10 minutes from date like this(Jan 1 Mon 2014 00:05) and get date like that(Dec 31 Sun 2013 23:55)

It would be awesome if there was such function for "struct tm" type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c) shows enough functions (mktime, localtime) to convert `struct tm` with `time_t`.  Calculations are obvious with `time_t` because it is an integral type traditionally representing the number of seconds since newyear 1970.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if there are any method for `struct tm` but I think you should read about `chrono` available in `C++11`.
[Link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)

Comment: Well, there's `difftime`, that's only a `mktime` away from `struct tm`.

Comment: `chrono` won't help with handling calendar dates. You'll need `mktime` and friends from the C library, or a third-party library like Boost.DateTime, for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++11 you can substract and add dates easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  chrono::system_clock::time_point today = chrono::system_clock::now();
  chrono::system_clock::duration dtn (chrono::duration<int,ratio<60,1>>(10));

  time_t t = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(today-dtn);
  cout << ctime(&t) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```